# What is the difference between complex and real coherneces?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, coherence, two-level-system

If we have one density matrix

$$\rho=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&&1/2\\1/2&&1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

for the state $\lvert\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\lvert g\rangle+\lvert e\rangle)$

and a different one

$$\rho=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&&i/2\\-i/2&&1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

for the state $\lvert\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(i\lvert g\rangle+\lvert e\rangle)$

What are the differences between these two states? Is there some physical meaning?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the norms of these states?

Comment: @Ice-Nine they are both 1 right?

Comment: suggest you change title to "difference between *complex* and real coherences".  "imaginary" could imply you're imagining things.

Comment: What is the effect of the complex rather than real phase difference?